# Springboot Generic JPA AttributeConverter

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have below sample code, i am trying to write generic JPA converter which could convert,

- Collection of user defined objects to Json
- vice versa

Below is sample code I was trying to achieve the result but looks like it's not correct.

Please take a look.

To be more clear i need like below

- List To string
- Json String to List

Please suggest

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class SetJsonConverter<E extends Collections> implements AttributeConverter<E, Object> {


    @Override
    public Object convertToDatabaseColumn(E e) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public E convertToEntityAttribute(Object o) {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA will not automatically handle generic converters. Each collection type and element type will require subclassing. You will need to define the base converter the following way:

```
public class AbstractJsonConverter<T, C extends Collection<T>> implements AttributeConverter<C, String> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final TypeReference<C> collectionType;

    public AbstractJsonConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper, Class<T> elementType, TypeReference<C> collectionType) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.collectionType = collectionType;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(C collection) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(collection);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public C convertToEntityAttribute(String jsonString) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, collectionType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

}
```

You then define specific converters as:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class UserSetConverter extends AbstractJsonConverter<User, Set<User>> {
    public UserSetConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        super(objectMapper, User.class, new TypeReference<Set<User>>() {});
    }
}
```